# jQuery accordion header different width than content

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using a jquery accordion with just one content panel like so:

```
<ul id="myaccordion">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Header Title</a>
        <div>
            Content in here.
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and then calling:

```
$('#myaccordion').accordion();
```

The problem I'm having is that the content part of the accrodion id the correct width, but the header is merely the width of the text that says 'Header Title' and this text is overlapping the arrow icon.

Can anyone see why the header wouldn't be the same width as my content? I have tried setting a specific with to the ul, the li and the a tags, but to no effect.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accordion code [expects a header around that anchor](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) for styling (or *any* wrapper element really), since this styling here needs it:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a { display: block; font-size: 1em; padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em; }
.ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a { padding-left: 2.2em; }
```

Just add a wrapper in there, like this:

```
<ul id="myaccordion">
    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">Header Title</a></h3>
        <div>
            Content in here.
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Here's a demo showing both with and without the `<h3>`, so you can see the effect](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/zu7BT/).

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the reply. It's working great now. Fo some reason in my jquery-ui book the source html didn't have a wrapper round the <a> tags. Do we need a wrapper because the <a> element doesn't expand to fit the space it's in, whereas things like <h3> do?

Comment: @Joe - It's not quite that, it's that it applied the `.ui-accordion-header` class directly to the element it finds, then looks for an `<a>` *inside* that with the styling, when there's just the `<a>` (and no `<a>` inside the `<a>` to be found) then the styling just isn't targeting right.

Comment: i have a stackoverflow question about a swapping link with my query accordion. would you be able to help me understand what i'm doing wrong? http://goo.gl/LszYl